# An expression of type ... cannot be handled by a pattern when class is sealed

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am getting a rather strange error:

`CS8121 An expression of type 'IGrouping<string, IMyInterface>' cannot be handled by a pattern of type 'MyClass1'.`

The error is occuring on the line:

`if(tGroup is MyClass1 myclass1)`

However, no error is provided for `MyClass2` which is not sealed.

1. What is causing this?
2. Other than not sealing `MyClass1` what solutions are there?

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main()
        {

            IEnumerable<IMyInterface> myInterfaces = new List<IMyInterface>();
            foreach (IGrouping<String, IMyInterface> tGroup in myInterfaces.GroupBy(x => x.XXX))
            {
                if(tGroup is MyClass1 myclass1)
                {
                }
                if(tGroup is MyClass2 myClass2)
                {
                }
            }

        }

    }

    public interface IMyInterface 
    {
        String XXX { get; } 
    }

    public sealed class MyClass1 : IMyInterface
    {
        public String XXX { get; }
    }

    public class MyClass2 : IMyInterface
    {
        public String XXX { get; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Iterating over the result of a groupby should return the elements (IMyInterface) and not IGrouping<T,T>?

Comment: the *group* isn't a `MyClass`, but some of the *items in the group* might be

Comment: @Ralf iterating over a *group* should return the elements; the result of groupby is the groups themselves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If MyClass is sealed, then there will never be a subclass that inherits `MyClass` and implements `IGrouping<string, IMyInterface>`
The compiler is smart enough to deduce that, and hence "complains".

If it is not sealed there could be something like this:

```
class WhatEver : MyClass, IGrouping<string, IMyInterface> { ... }
```

So the compile cannot rule out if the `is` will ever succeed.

**edit**
I bellieve, what you actually want to do is something like this:

```
foreach (IGrouping<String, IMyInterface> tGroup in myInterfaces.GroupBy(x => x.XXX))
{
    foreach(IMyInterface item in tGroup)
    {
        if(item is MyClass1 myclass1)
        {
        }
        if(item is MyClass2 myClass2)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have expanded the demo to show MyClass1 and MyClass2. I do not quite understand, as the IMyInterface may well be of type MyClass1 or MyClass2, so why would this not work?

Comment: @HarryWill you seem to be confusing the *groups* vs the *contents of the groups*; the group is not your type - it is an inbuilt LINQ thing, and it never implements your interface

Comment: Because you probably mean to check  one of the Items of `tGroup`
Check my Edit @HarryWill